# C Socket Download .exe 6 times larger?

Tags: c, windows, sockets

I am trying to make a little program to download an exe and save it locally using winsock2.h it works, like it downloads the file and saves it. But the end file is almost 6 times larger then the actual file it downloads. I can't seem to figure out why. The file I am trying to download and save locally is ccleaner403.exe for example it is around 4mb's yet the end result is 36 mb's. Obviously there is still HTTP headers in there, but those aren't 32mb's. The file is a little long so I just cropped out the "file writing part". If you need the rest just ask.

```
#define BUFSIZE 4096

// Receive the data
memset(buf, 0, sizeof(buf));

// Open file for writing
fp = fopen("stuff.exe", "wb");

header = 0;
test = 0;

while ((tmpres = recv(sock, buf, BUFSIZ, 0)) > 0)
{

    fwrite(buf, 1, sizeof(buf), fp);
    memset(buf, 0, tmpres);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Each time around the loop, you are always writing `sizeof(buf)` bytes to the file, which is most likely larger than the actual number of bytes received in `tmpres`.

Change `sizeof(buf)` to `tmpres` in the call to `fwrite()`. (Then remove the call to `memset()`. It's unnecessary.)

Comment: I hate it when people read over my shoulder and then type faster than me.  :D

Comment: I'm still playing around with this strange thing, there is two `memsets` that do nothing... not sure why they are there. I probably had good intentions, but just never finished it.

Comment: @Steven if you use memset you'll have a clear memory and then you would be able to count how much you recieved by using strlen instead of sizeof. However this would not allow your recieved data to contain NULL (which you must allow since it is binary data). So it's the wrong approach and you should listen to duskwuff, however this is one case for using memset...

Answer (score 2):

The return value from `recv()` tells you how many bytes were actually read each time.  You ignore that and blithely assume that the buffer was filled.  It most probably wasn't.

You need:

```
while ((tmpres = recv(sock, buf, BUFSIZ, 0)) > 0)
{
    if (fwrite(buf, 1, tempres, fp) != tempres)
        ...oops...failed to write...
}
```

You really don't need the `memset()`.